# Определение типа захватываемой лямбдой переменной

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


int main() {
    int x, &y = x;
    [=] {
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype((x)), int>
                  << std::is_same_v<decltype((x)), int&>
                  << std::is_same_v<decltype((x)), int const&>;

        std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype((y)), int>
                  << std::is_same_v<decltype((y)), int&>
                  << std::is_same_v<decltype((y)), int const&>;
    }();
}
```

Компилятор gcc выводит `001010`, а clang - `001001`. Какой вариант правильный и почему?

Comment: Стоит уточнять версии компиляторов и параметры сборки. А вообще это похоже на баг в clang.

Comment: @VTT последние версии: gcc - 8.2.1, clang - 7.0.0; параметры -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic

Comment: а без лямбды что он выводит?

Comment: У вас ещё скобки `(())` двойные внутри `decltype`, которые несколько меняют смысл. Это специально добавлено, чтобы добавить нюансов, или зачем?

Comment: Скобки `(())` - критичны. Без таких скобок бы не было никакого capture и `decltype` бы относился к внешней переменной. Именно благодаря этим скобкам `decltype` работает именно с захваченной переменной.

Comment: [Схожий вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894748/lambda-capture-reference-by-copy-and-decltype)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Достаточно запутанный вопрос, но похоже, что `clang` прав.

---

Для начала рассмотрим, как определяется тип выражения `E` в `decltype(E)`.

[[dcl.type.decltype]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.type.decltype#1):

> For an expression E, the type denoted by `decltype(E)` is defined as
> follows:
>
> - if E is an unparenthesized *id-expression* naming a structured binding ([[dcl.struct.bind]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.struct.bind)), `decltype(E)` is the referenced type as given in the specification of the structured binding declaration;
> - otherwise, if E is an unparenthesized *id-expression* naming a non-type *template-parameter*, `decltype(E)` is the type of the *template-parameter* after performing any necessary type deduction ([[dcl.spec.auto]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.spec.auto), [[dcl.type.class.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.type.class.deduct));
> - otherwise, if E is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access ([[expr.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.ref)), `decltype(E)` is the type of the entity named by E. If there is no such entity, or if E names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if E is an xvalue, `decltype(E)` is T&&, where T is the type of E;
> - otherwise, if E is an lvalue, `decltype(E)` is T&, where T is the type of E;
> - otherwise, decltype(E) is the type of E.

`x` и `y` являются *glvalue*, но не являются *xvalue*, а значит являются *lvalue* в соответствии с [[basic.lval]/fig:basic.lval](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.lval#fig:basic.lval):

[image: fig_1]

Таким образом, срабатывает предпоследний пункт определения типа, то есть варианты с `int` отпадают сразу.

Далее, рассмотрим следующую цитату.

[[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.prim.lambda.capture#11):

> Every *id-expression* within the *compound-statement* of a
> *lambda-expression* that is an *odr-use* of an entity captured by copy is
> transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of
> the closure type. [ Note: An *id-expression* that is not an odr-use
> refers to the original entity, never to a member of the closure type.
> **However, such an *id-expression* can still cause the implicit capture of
> the entity.** — end note ] ...

В данном случае выражения не являются потенциально вычисляемыми (т.к. [являются операндами decltype](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.type#decltype-1)), а значит соответствующие переменные не являются *odr-использованными*. Однако важно примечание — такие выражения всё ещё могут рассматриваться в контексте *лямбда-замыканий*, что подтверждается следующей цитатой.

[[expr.prim.id.unqual]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.prim.id.unqual#2):

> ... If the entity is a local entity and naming it from outside of an
> unevaluated operand within the declarative region where the
> *unqualified-id* appears would result in some intervening
> *lambda-expression* capturing it by copy ([[expr.prim.lambda.capture]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.prim.lambda.capture)),
> the type of the expression is the type of a class member access
> expression ([[expr.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.ref)) naming the non-static data member that would
> be declared for such a capture in the closure object of the innermost
> such intervening *lambda-expression*. [ Note: If that *lambda-expression*
> is not declared `mutable`, the type of such an identifier will **typically**
> be const qualified. — end note ] ...

Другими словами, несмотря на то что захвата не происходит, тип выражения определяется так, как будто бы захват есть. Также в примечании сказано про константность идентификатора, если лямбда не имеет спецификатора `mutable`, что подтверждается следующим пунктом.

[[expr.prim.labmda.closure]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.prim.lambda.closure#4):

> The function call operator or operator template is declared `const`
> ([[class.mfct.non-static]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/class.mfct.non-static)) **if and only if** the *lambda-expression*'s
> *parameter-declaration-clause* is not followed by `mutable`. ...

---

Интересно, что из-за нечёткости формулировок и разбросанности их по разным разделам стандарта (на мой взгляд) оба компилятора имеют соответствующие баг-репорты: [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66672), [clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35423). На момент 2022 года оба компилятора признали правильным поведение `clang`, однако в `gcc` баг до сих пор не исправлен.

Comment: Так ведь «typically» это всё таки не «always». А закрытие как «Resolved invalid» подразумевает, что это и не баг вовсе, кмк.

Comment: @älёxölüt  я специально выделил «typically» и «if and only if», чтобы показать некоторое несоответствие между пунктами стандарта. Но «if and only if», конечно, более сильное утверждение. Что касается багрепорта в `clang` - да, они не признали это багом; обратного я и не утверждал. Это косвенно даже подтверждает, что `clang` прав

Comment: Стандарт не консистентен, особенно его черновик. "if and only if", конечно сильнее, согласен.

Answer (score 3):

При захвате по значению `[=]` переменные [захватываются копированием](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10). Для каждой захваченной сущности создаётся безымянный член данных внутри лямбда объекта. Для ссылок на объекты тип получается тоже ссылочный:

> The type of such a data member **is the referenced type if the entity is a reference to an object**, an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity is a reference to a function, or the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise.

Так как уточнения о том, какой должна быть ссылка: `const` или `не-const` нет, оба рассмотренных компилятора дают подходящий под стандарт результат. Однако, известно, что для модификации, захваченных по значению сущностей нужно дополнительно помечать лямбду как `mutable`. И если это сделать, можно увидеть, что оба компилятора уже будут давать одинаковые результаты ([clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BuHTiDzf8yWONANa), [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8jXM6eYW3t5mgnrP)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    int x = 42, &y = x;
    [=]() mutable {
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype((y)), int>
                  << std::is_same_v<decltype((y)), int&>
                  << std::is_same_v<decltype((y)), int const&>;

        x = 0;
        y = 100500;
    }();

    std::cout << "\n" << x << "\n";
}
```

> ```
> 010
> 42
> ```

Так как требуется явная модификация `y = 100500`, то тип `y` уже не может быть константной ссылкой и становится обычной ссылкой. Модифицируются же по-прежнему копии внутри лямбды.

Comment: Сущность захватывается копированием, если она захватывается явно или неявно. Но чтобы захватить её неявно, она должна быть odr-использованной, но это не так. Так что первая часть ответа мне кажется не совсем верной

Comment: @VTT понятно, что ссылку нельзя переназначить, но это уже другая константность. Я о константности объекта, на который указывает ссылка. В примерах кода вопроса/ответа есть оба вида ссылок.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш пример практически повторяет пример из C++17 стандарта языка.

```
void f3() {
  float x, &r = x;
  [=] { 
  // x and r are not captured (appearance in a decltype operand is not an odr-use)
    decltype(x) y1; 
    // y1 has type float

    decltype((x)) y2 = y1; 
    // y2 has type float const& because this lambda is not mutable and x is an lvalue

    decltype(r) r1 = y1; 
    // r1 has type float& (transformation not considered)

    decltype((r)) r2 = y2; 
    // r2 has type float const&
  }; 
}
```

Форма `decltype((x))` не является *odr-use* для `x`, т.е. она не вызывает неявного захвата `x`, но она должна вести себя так, *как будто* `x` было захвачено и `decltype((x))` ссылается именно на захваченное `x`.

При захвате ссылки по значению происходит захват по значению именно ссылаемого объекта. Таким образом никакой разницы в способах `x` и `y` захвата в вашем примере нет. Ваши захваченные `x` и `y` имеют тип `int`. Внутри тела не-mutable лямбды они видны как lvalues типа `const int`. Т.е. в контексте тела вашей лямбды и `decltype((x))` и `decltype((y))` дают тип `const int &`.

Однако эта часть стандарта подвергается переработке для C++20. Возможно, что есть изменения.

Comment: @VTT:  Как "почему"? Еще раз: при захвате по значению захватывается не ссылка, а сам **объект, на который ссылка ссылается**. Так как ламбда не mutable, все захваты являются `const`. Указатели тоже будут `const`, но указатели захватываются сами по себе (т.е. захватваются сами указатели, а не указуемые объекты), т.е. `const` попадает на сам указатель.

Comment: В `decltype((r))` ссылочный тип - это не захваченная ссылка. Ссылочный тип в `decltype((r))` - это просто проявление того факта, что захваченное `r` является lvalue типа `const float`. Это "новая" ссылка. Не вижу никакой проблемы с копипастой.